# Doxygen not working for C structure's forward declaration

Tags: c, doxygen

I have below code in a C header file:

```
/** \brief Forward declaration for instance object. */
typedef struct CbData_t CbData;

/**
 * \brief Callback function prototype.
 *
 * \param cbData  [OUT] Callback Data. Refer #CbData
 * \return None.
 */
typedef void (*cbFxn)(CbData cbData);

/**
 * \brief Structure containing callback data.
 */
struct CbData_t
{
    uint32_t id;
    /**< Id for which interrupt has occurred */
};
```

When I try to create doxygen (version 1.8.13), I get the below error:

```
warning: explicit link request to 'CbData' could not be resolved
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you define `struct CbData_t` before `cbFxn`?

Comment: This would have been ideal as I won't need forward declaration then. Unfortunately I can't structure the code in this way.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Would it help when you wrote as the first line `/** \file */` ?

Comment: I am using doxygen 1.8.13

Comment: Look to me that adding the first line as indicated might work with 1.8.13 as well.

Comment: Albert, This snippet is portion of a large header file. File comment is already there

Comment: Something else must be the problem as I didn't get the warning at any time of my tests.

Comment: Albert, which version did you try?

Comment: @RogMatthews Sorry for the late comment: 1.8.14 and current master using the standard (doxygen -g) Doxyfile. (To address a specific person use the`@` syntax).